# Why just first 5 seconds of UNNotificationSound plays

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, notifications

After updating to iOS 10.1.1 the iOS Notification custom sound stop after 5 seconds.

**This happens only if device is turned on, but it plays whole 30 seconds if device is off.**

The `UNNotificationSound` documentation says:

> You can package the audio data in an aiff, wav, or caf file. Sound
>   files must be less than 30 seconds in length. If the sound file is
>   longer than 30 seconds, the system plays the default sound instead.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unnotificationsound

So if we're able to set 30 second sound files, then there must be a way of allowing them to play for 30 seconds not only 5?

Comment: I think it works different from the user's perspective.. 5 seconds plays if user is in the phone doing something; 30 seconds plays if notification triggered while the phone is locked or screen is off.

Comment: This comment should be the accepted answer... even tho Apple make no mention of it, since iOS 10 we only get the full 30 second playback in the lock screen, otherwise it's just 5 seconds.

Answer (score 11):

Notifications last no longer than 5 seconds when the device is **unlocked**, by default. You can't change this behavior programmatically. But the user can change the Notifications settings for the app, so banners will not hide after 5 seconds. She need to set **Banner Style** to **Persistent**.
[image: This problem was successfully solved in Periodic Timer + app.]